# On OSX, why does 'find . -atime 1' list files I haven't accessed?

Tags: macos

On OSX Mavericks, I was recently trying to remember "what the heck was I doing X days ago?".  In the Terminal, I used "find . -atime X" and got a list of files that included ones I knew that I never accessed in that time frame.  Am I seeing the footprints of Spotlight?  Or worse, is something sinister patiently trying to find something useful on my disk?

Answer (score 1):

Access time is a property of the file and does not concern itself with *what* is accessing the file.

It may be you looking at it, it may be your anti-virus program checking it, it may be an indexer (a la Spotlight) analysing it to speed up queries at a later time ("show me all files with the word 'xyzzy' in it"), or it may be a backup solution (a la Time Machine) protecting your files for you.

Or, it *could* be something nefarious, though that's probably less likely than the other alternatives.

Comment: pax -- what you say makes perfect sense, but poses the question: does a query for a file's last-accessed time reset the last-accessed time?  The reason that I ask is that the files that caught my eye in the 'find' were dead-letters years ago.  One reason I feel safe from snooping by NSA or black-hat-hackers is that I myself can't figure out how to find salient files in all the stuff on my disk that used to make sense to me.  What hope does someone who isn't actively malicious towards me (and willing to invest a lot of effort) have?